# Arduino Python Multiple Ultrasonic sensors upload to MySQL

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python, arduino-ide

```
import os
from time import *
import time
import threading
import serial
import datetime
import sys
import MySQLdb as mdb
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)
distances =  ser.readline()
distances.splitlines
distances=distances.splitlines()
try:
  con = mdb.connect('130.127.199.212', 'root', 'Fr24clemson', 'autonomous');
  cur = con.cursor()
except:
    print "Error opening serial port."
    sys.exit(1)

    resp = ""
    droptable="DROP TABLE autonomous.ultrasonic_sensor_data"
    cur.execute(droptable)
    createtable="CREATE TABLE autonomous.ultrasonic_sensor_data (n_FL DOUBLE NULL  ,w_FR DOUBLE NULL,n_RL DOUBLE NULL  ,w_RR DOUBLE NULL,t_unixtime DOUBLE NULL,t_time TIMESTAMP)"
    cur.execute(createtable)
try:
        while True:
         for d in distances : 
          d=d.split(' ')
          print d
         FL=float(d[0])
         FR=float(d[1])
         RL=float(d[2])
         RR=float(d[3])
         unixtime=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s")
         sql = "insert into ultrasonic_sensor_data(n_FL, w_FR, n_RL, w_RR,  t_unixtime) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % (FL,FR,RL,RR, unixtime)
         print sql
         cur.execute(sql)
         print "Rows inserted: %s" % cur.rowcount
         con.commit()
         time.sleep(1)#set to whatever
         resp = ""
except:
        print sys.exc_info()[0]

finally:
        if con:
         con.close()
time.sleep(1) #set to whatever
```

My current code. Problem is the same value of the sensor is now getting struck the values inserted are not the updated ones.
This is the output
insert into ultrasonic_sensor_data(n_FL, w_FR, n_RL, w_RR,  t_unixtime) values(33.0, 12.0, 133.0, 37.0, 1468345652)
Rows inserted: 1
['33', '12', '133', '37']
insert into ultrasonic_sensor_data(n_FL, w_FR, n_RL, w_RR,  t_unixtime) values(33.0, 12.0, 133.0, 37.0, 1468345653)
Rows inserted: 1
['33', '12', '133', '37']
insert into ultrasonic_sensor_data(n_FL, w_FR, n_RL, w_RR,  t_unixtime) values(33.0, 12.0, 133.0, 37.0, 1468345654)
Rows inserted: 1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the values out of that string into a list:

```
l = ['39 15 12 18']
to_insert = map(lambda x: int(x),l[0].split())
```

Then insert with:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect('your connection details')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('insert into your_table (s1, s2, s3, s4) values (%s,%s,%s,%s);',to_insert)
```